# How to render React.Component on mouse enter/leave events

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mouseevent

Have a problem with rendering react component on `onMouseEnter`, `onMouseLeave` events in the list of items

I have a list of items

```
const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false)
...
{data.categories.map((item) => (
  <>
    <li
      key={item.id}
      className="list-item"
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        setHover(true);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        setHover(false);
      }}
    >
      <NavLink
        to={`/catalogues/${item.name_parameterized}`}
        className="list-item-link"
        activeClassName="active"
      >
        {item.name}
      </NavLink>
    </li>
    {isHover && <SubCategory data={item.children} />}
  </>
))}
```

Need to show `SubCategory Component with different data` on the `onMouseLeave` / `onMouseEnter` events on the every `li`
If i do something like this

```
<ul>
<li>
...
isHover && <SubCategory>
<li>
<ul>
```

I see that `<SubCategory>` shown `items.length` times but I need to show only **one** `<SubCategory>` for hovering `li` only

[Expected result is how on the Walmart site subcategories shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFVIM.png)

Comment: Can you add to question from where `isHover` variable comes from as well as `setHover` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In other words you need a different *state* for each element, therefore you also need a Component for each:

```
function ShowOnHover({ item }) {
  const [isHover, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
   <>
     <li
      key={item.id}
      onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
     >
     <NavLink
      to={`/catalogues/${item.name_parameterized}`}
      className="list-item-link"
      activeClassName="active"
     >
      {item.name}
     </NavLink>
    </li>
    {isHover && <SubCategory data={item.children} />}
    </>
   );
}
```

Then use that component as:

```
data.categories.map((item) => <ShowOnHover item={item} />)
```